# Unique value in nested list - random

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a largely working program, it creates nested lists of size set by user and repeats based on user input.

However I want the individual sets to only contain unique values currently this is my output.

```
> python3 testv.py 
Size of your Range?: 12
Size of your Sets?: 3
How many sets?: 4
[['Two', 'Seven', 'Five'], ['Four', 'Six', 'Two'], ['Three', 'Five', 'Thirteen'], ['Six', 'Two', 'Two']]
```

This is my program and x is my list comprehension to create my nested lists, is there a good way to define this to keep the values unique.

```
import random


class WeightedRandomizer:

    def __init__(self, weights):
        self.__max = .0
        self.__weights = []
        for value, weight in weights.items():
            self.__max += weight
            self.__weights.append((self.__max, value))

    def random(self):
        r = random.random() * self.__max
        for ceil, value in self.__weights:
            if ceil > r:
                return value


range_size = 0
if range_size == 0:
    try:
        rSize = int(input('Size of your Range?: '))
        setSize = int(input('Size of your Sets?: '))
        numSets = int(input('How many sets?: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('That was not an integer!')
        range_size = 0


base_value = 100 / rSize
num_weighted = [base_value] * rSize
num_weighted[0] = round(base_value * 2.2, 1)
num_weighted[1] = round(base_value * 1.8, 1)
num_weighted[2] = round(base_value * 1.8, 1)
num_weighted[3] = round(base_value * 1.5, 1)
num_weighted[4] = round(base_value * 1.4, 1)
num_weighted[5] = round(base_value * 1.3, 1)


# redistribute the difference of top 6 and rest of range
top6 = (sum(num_weighted[0:6]))
not_top6 = rSize - 6
pts_alloc = round((100 - top6) / not_top6, 1)

num_weighted[6:] = [pts_alloc for i in range(len(num_weighted) - 6)]

keys = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight',
        'Nine', 'Ten', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen']

dictionary = dict(zip(keys, num_weighted))

wr = WeightedRandomizer(dictionary)

x = [[wr.random() for i in range(setSize)] for j in range(numSets)]

print(x)
```

Comment: I see it's not just random values—can you please elaborate on what properties you want your sets to have besides containing random values? The code is not the easiest one to understand for somebody who's not highly motivated to get familiar with it.

Comment: @ErikAllik  I have created a weighted random ref (http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/) I want to use this weighted random to create sets where each set has unique elements drawn via the weighted random. so ['Two', 'Seven', 'Five'] is ok but ['Six', 'Two', 'Two'] is not but values can be repeated across lists just not within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to your class:

```
def take(self, amount):
    ret = []
    while True:
        item = self.random()
        if item in ret:
            continue
        ret.append(item)
        if len(ret) == amount:
            return ret
```

And then change your list-comprehension to this:

```
x = [wr.take(setSize) for j in range(numSets)]
```

---

Basically the answer is getting random items and then storing them until you have the required amount of unique ones.

---

Should look like this:

```
import random


class WeightedRandomizer:

    def __init__(self, weights):
        self.__max = .0
        self.__weights = []
        for value, weight in weights.items():
            self.__max += weight
            self.__weights.append((self.__max, value))

    def take(self, amount):
        ret = []
        while True:
            item = self.random()
            if item in ret:
                continue
            ret.append(item)
            if len(ret) == amount:
                return ret

    def random(self):
        r = random.random() * self.__max
        for ceil, value in self.__weights:
            if ceil > r:
                return value


range_size = 0
if range_size == 0:
    try:
        rSize = int(input('Size of your Range?: '))
        setSize = int(input('Size of your Sets?: '))
        numSets = int(input('How many sets?: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('That was not an integer!')
        range_size = 0


base_value = 100 / rSize
num_weighted = [base_value] * rSize
num_weighted[0] = round(base_value * 2.2, 1)
num_weighted[1] = round(base_value * 1.8, 1)
num_weighted[2] = round(base_value * 1.8, 1)
num_weighted[3] = round(base_value * 1.5, 1)
num_weighted[4] = round(base_value * 1.4, 1)
num_weighted[5] = round(base_value * 1.3, 1)


# redistribute the difference of top 6 and rest of range
top6 = (sum(num_weighted[0:6]))
not_top6 = rSize - 6
pts_alloc = round((100 - top6) / not_top6, 1)

num_weighted[6:] = [pts_alloc for i in range(len(num_weighted) - 6)]

keys = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight',
        'Nine', 'Ten', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen']

dictionary = dict(zip(keys, num_weighted))

wr = WeightedRandomizer(dictionary)

x = [wr.take(setSize) for j in range(numSets)]

print(x)
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code to a new file. When I ran it I got duplicates in some sets.  > python3 testx.py
Size of your Range?: 12
Size of your Sets?: 3
How many sets?: 10
[['Two', 'Ten', 'One'], ['Four', 'Eight', 'Two'], ['Four', 'Three', 'Six'], ['One', 'Five', 'One'], ['One', 'Five', 'Six'], ['One', 'One', 'Two'], ['Two', 'Six', 'One'], ['Seven', 'One', 'Five'], ['Ten', 'Two', 'Four'], ['Four', 'Two', 'Nine']]

Comment: yes - I had a typo - try it now. Sorry. (Called the random function again, instead of adding the item that that already had.)